# Codeigniter combine mobile and normal site

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, mobile

For my website I also want to integrate a mobile version.

I won't use responsive design since I'm not sure that in the end everything from the regular site will be needed on the mobile version.

So I want to integrate the mobile version in my current project since I'll need the models and most of the controllers. So basically most of the resources will be the same.

I don't feel the need to rewrite all of my controllers in a second app or something.

Simply check in my controllers is it's a mobile device each time I load a view doesn't seem the most elegant solution to me.

We are also developing an API (for future mobile app and such stuff) would it be a solution to create a standalone app and do all the communication via an API?

Any tips or ideas how to create this in an efficient way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the User Agent Library, it provides several methods to handle mobile request, for example:

```
$this->agent->is_mobile();
```

You can check your visitor user agent with this library and then load the proper view.

More info: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/user_agent.html

Comment: I know how to track if a user is on mobile device.

But this means that I have to do a check every single time I load a view in all of my controllers. I was wondering if there was a more elegant way of doing this.

Something like a master controller (default) to check whether it's a mobile device or not and according to the result redirect them to the mobile or desktop version.

And I also know how to code that select stuff, the problem is I wonder how I can reuse my controller and models in the mobile part.

Comment: A master controller can be used if you choose to layout your app like that, you could then check if mobile once and redirect the program flow from there. An alternative would be to load the value to a config file and then retrieve it from there rather than calling the is_mobile() method each time. All depends how often you need to know throughout your program flow. Your models should be pretty similar but you may want to pass them an is_mobile parameter which alters the data which is returned. In short, m4t1t0 has told you how to do it but how you put that into practice depends on your needs